# Convert all shape to image in Ms word with macro

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office

I write this macro to convert all shapes in document to image :

```
Sub AllShapeToPic()    
   For Each oShp In ActiveDocument.Shapes
    oShp.Select
    Selection.Cut
    Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile, _
        Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
   Next oShp

End Sub
```

But when i run it , none of shapes converted to image.
Whats wrong in my macro code ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of manipulating the very collection you are looping through.
The moment you cut, you are effectively removing the shape from the collection, altering your loop.

If you want to loop through shapes (or table rows or whatever) and delete something from that collection, simply go backwards:

```
Dim i As Integer, oShp As Shape

For i = ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set oShp = ActiveDocument.Shapes(i)
    oShp.Select
    Selection.Cut
    Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, dataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile, _
        Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
Next i
```

Alternatively for Tables **(warning: untested!)**

```
Dim tbl As Table

For i = ActiveDocument.Tables.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(i)
    tbl.Select
    Selection.Cut
    Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, dataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile, _
        Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
Next i
```

For equations: Equations are InlineShapes and have a "OMath" property. Use it to identify an equation object. **Warning: untested**

```
Dim equation As InlineShape

For i = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set equation = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(i)
    If equation.OMath > 0 Then
        equation.Select
        Selection.Cut
        Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, dataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile, _
            Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , let me try it :)

Comment: Sorry but can you help me that how can i do this for tables and formulas ?

Comment: Note: an image can be "floating" (=shape) or "moving with characters" (inline).
 In the second case, replace "ActiveDocument.Shapes" by "ActiveDocument.InlineShapes", or macro won't work properly. Also change " oShp As Shape" to " oShp As InlineShape". Or probably it's better to have two separate cycles for the two types.