# Convert formula in a word document to image with macro

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office

I have this macro to convert all shapes in the document to an image :

```
Dim i As Integer, oShp As Shape

For i = ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set oShp = ActiveDocument.Shapes(i)
    oShp.Select
    Selection.Cut
    Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, dataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile, _
        Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
Next i
```

But I want to convert all math formulas to image. How can I change this macro to do this?
[image]

**UPDATE:**
I tried this code but doesnt work : (No error and also no result)

```
Sub AllEquationToPic()
Dim z As Integer, equation As OMath

For z = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set equation = ActiveDocument.OMaths(z)
        equation.Range.Select
        Selection.Cut
        Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile, _
            Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
Next z
End Sub
```

Comment: Check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537325/convert-all-shape-to-image-in-ms-word-with-macro/31538132#31538132

Comment: Hey, you're the same guy! What was wrong with my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are iterating through the `InlineShapes` collection but using `z` to access the `OMaths` collection. That's nonsense.
Try this then:

```
Sub AllEquationToPic()
Dim z As Integer, equation As OMath

For z = ActiveDocument.OMaths.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set equation = ActiveDocument.OMaths(z)
        equation.Range.Select
        Selection.Cut
        Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile, _
            Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
Next z
End Sub
```

**Edit:** Here is an alternative that works better with inline formulae albeit with slightly worse resulting image quality:

```
Sub FormulaDoc2PicDoc()
Dim doc As Document, docPath As String, htmPath As String
Dim alertStatus

alertStatus = Application.DisplayAlerts
Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone

Set doc = ActiveDocument
docPath = doc.FullName
htmPath = docPath & ".htm"

doc.SaveAs htmPath, wdFormatFilteredHTML
doc.Close False

Application.DisplayAlerts = alertStatus

Set doc = Documents.Open(htmPath, False)

End Sub
```

Comment: Work fine :) ( I ask this Q because your code in your linked answer doesn’t work then i decide to ask in a new question )

Comment: This is excellent. However, is there any way to paste only the equation, without the white space that surrounds it? Many thanks.

Comment: @LocEngineer - very clever, thanks for that! If you discover a way to keep the equations as vector images I would be most grateful, as I need to print the document.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [other values for DataType](http://www.bettersolutions.com/word/WNV283/LY521251611.htm)

- wdPasteBitmap
- wdPasteDeviceIndependentBitmap
- wdPasteEnhancedMetafile
- wdPasteHTML
- wdPasteHyperlink
- wdPasteMetafilePicture
- wdPasteOLEObject
- wdPasteRTF
- wdPasteShape
- wdPasteText