# OMath output and display of fractions into Excel

Tags: excel, vba, math, ms-word, equation

**INTRO**
With this code it is possible to display mathematical equation within a WORD document:

```vb
Sub genEQ()
    Dim objRange As Range
    Dim objEq As OMath
    Dim AC As OMathAutoCorrectEntry
    Application.OMathAutoCorrect.UseOutsideOMath = True
    Set objRange = Selection.Range
    objRange.Text = "Celsius = \sqrt(x+y) + sin(5/9 \times(Fahrenheit – 23 (\delta)^2))"
    For Each AC In Application.OMathAutoCorrect.Entries
        With objRange
            If InStr(.Text, AC.Name) > 0 Then
                .Text = Replace(.Text, AC.Name, AC.Value)
            End If
        End With
    Next AC
    Set objRange = Selection.OMaths.Add(objRange)
    Set objEq = objRange.OMaths(1)
    objEq.BuildUp
End Sub
```

An with this code I am able to display UNICODE characters within EXCEL message boxes without displaying "?" or "random characters":

```vb
Private Declare PtrSafe Function MessageBoxW Lib "User32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpText As LongPtr, ByVal lpCaption As LongPtr, ByVal uType As Long) As Long

Public Function MsgBoxW(Prompt As String, Optional Buttons As VbMsgBoxStyle = vbOKOnly, Optional Title As String = "Microsoft Excel") As VbMsgBoxResult
    MsgBoxW = MessageBoxW(Application.hWnd, StrPtr(Prompt), StrPtr(Title), Buttons)
End Function
```

**QUESTION**

1. Is there now a way to combine those and display a complete equation within a message box in EXCEL?
   Further how do I refer to MS WORD with the above code snippet to be run within EXCEL?
2. Is there a way to display a fraction like in the formula of the first code without making a string with a " / "-symbol?

Comment: An equation is not a piece of text. It is an object that can draw itself as a picture. You cannot display anything other than text in a message box. You can copy the equation [as a picture](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31579710/11683) and proceed with a userform from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by @GSerg, you need to go through an intermediary picture and use a userform rather than a message box.

The following code converts the text to a formula and goes via Publisher to save the picture then loads it into a pre-existing UserForm `UserForm1` with image placeholder `Image1`. I have increased font size to get better resolution for the picture but this can be set to other values.

> Updated to work with autocorrect formulae

```
Sub DisplayFormulae()
    ' Requires reference: Microsoft Word x.x Object Library
    ' Requires reference: Microsoft Publisher x.x Object Library
    
    Dim sFormula As String: sFormula = "Celsius = \sqrt(x+y) + sin(5/9 \times(Fahrenheit – 23 (\delta)^2))"
    Dim SaveName As String: SaveName = Environ("TEMP") & "\formula.jpg"
    
    Dim AC As Word.OMathAutoCorrectEntry
    
    Dim WordDoc As New Word.Document
    With WordDoc
        .Range.Text = sFormula
        .Range.Font.Size = 18
        For Each AC In .Parent.OMathAutoCorrect.Entries
            With .Range
                If InStr(.Text, AC.Name) > 0 Then
                    .Text = Replace(.Text, AC.Name, AC.Value)
                End If
            End With
        Next AC
        .OMaths.Add(.Range).OMaths(1).BuildUp
        .OMaths(1).Range.Copy
        .Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
    End With
    
    Dim PubDoc As New Publisher.Document
    PubDoc.Pages(1).Shapes.Paste
    PubDoc.Pages(1).Shapes(1).SaveAsPicture _
        PbResolution:=pbPictureResolutionCommercialPrint_300dpi, _
        Filename:=SaveName
    PubDoc.Close
    
    UserForm1.Controls("Image1").Picture = LoadPicture(SaveName)
    UserForm1.Show
    Kill SaveName
End Sub
```